# How can I run another Python script in a Python script?

Tags: python

I would like to run a Python script in another Python script. I understand that the best way to do that is importing that script. But I couldn't figure out how I can run that script every 60 seconds. What I have tried so far:

```
    import time
    import mailyolla

    while(1):
        mailyolla
        time.sleep(60)
```

and

```
    import time

    while(1):
        import mailyolla
        time.sleep(60)
```

Neither worked. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should define a main() function in your mailyolla file that is executing the task you want. Then, the above script would look like:

```
import time
import mailyolla

while(True):
    mailyolla.main()
    time.sleep(60)
```